# Prevent component reuse by self assigned key?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have many small React editor components that receive a document prop. I dont want them to be reused so I add a key to them:

```
<Editor key={doc1.id} doc={doc1}/>
```

I would love to derive the key automatically from the doc.id inside of the component class. Is this possible?

My aim is that I have a much cleaner:

```
<Editor doc={doc1}/>
```

Comment: You need to pass the `key` prop to the component from the rendering context - in other words, you will need to pass the `key` explicitly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keys are a special mechanism used to invalidate indentity of components (the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) explicitly mention the identity issue keys are solving) : if a react element in a react tree only differs with its key between two render passes its underlying component will be unmounted and remounted. Keys are mainly used when rendering a list, or to force unmount/mount for a specific component. So the answer to your question is no

React already tries to reuse a lot of the dom state if nothing changes and there are lyfecycle methods available to prevent unwanted rerenders: shouldComponentUpdate. However, as the docs state using this lifecycle should be considered performance optimization and will in the future considered as hint rather than as a directive. Unless there is a specific perf issue this could be  premature optimization IMO.

Comment: Sorry if I was a bit unclear: I just want to derive the key from other props.

Comment: in your question this is exactly what you do by using the doc id as a key. what I am saying is that this is a mechanism for validating component identity in a react tree. given two react trees, if a node within them only differs by its key then react will unmount and remount the corresponding component without calling willReceiveProps or sutff like that and rerender the corresponding sub tree. what you are looking for is actually not cleaner because it would obfuscate this essential behaviour.

Comment: Thanks. That last sentence answers my question.

Comment: thanks! I will try to find time to update my answer and make it clearer with your last comment.